# Relay System (Calculate relay points between origin and destination) with shortest path

Tags: javascript, geolocation, coordinates, geojson, geo

I am trying to build a relay delivery solution.

I have few coordinates (locations) inside a city.

```
let coordinates = [
        [77.676247, 12.926031, "Bellandur"],
        [77.697418, 12.959172, "Marathalli"],
        [77.749947, 12.9698, "Whitefield"],
        [77.623344, 12.917654, "Silkboard signal"],
        [77.60457, 12.95029, "Lalbagh Garden"],
    ];
```

And then I have an origin and destination.

```
let origin = [77.666847, 12.926131, "Origin"];
let destination = [77.746061, 12.957973, "Destination"];
```

The origin and destination are too far from each other, so I need to find sort of relay points in between so that a delivery person can drop the items at one of the points and another person can pick them up to drop at the destination.

Ideal route for this eg would be,

```
[
    [77.666847, 12.926131, "Origin"],
    [77.676247, 12.926031, "Bellandur"],
    [77.697418, 12.959172, "Marathalli"],
    [77.749947, 12.9698, "Whitefield"],
    [77.746061, 12.957973, "Destination"]
]
```

Visualization
[image]

Comment: where is the code, you tried? what goes wrong?

Comment: @NinaScholz I tried to find the nearest coordinates and use recursion further. It did not work because it always followed the same path. I am not looking for code, but an approach as to how to solve it.